# Can we use coco and peat moss at same time?

Tags: soil-amendment, potting-soil

As a soil mix, is it wise to use both coco  peat and peat moss to have the good of both the worlds?

Since some plants requires soil to dry out in between watering, peat moss will compact and pull away from the edges of the pot. It also gets a lot harder to re-wet peat moss once it dries. While this is not the case with coco peat, coco peat is devoid of nutrients (?) And I am wondering if mixing them both makes sense or not.

Comment: Peat does not have any nutrients either, so you'd be mixing two nutrient free substances together.

Comment: @Bamboo but peat is dead plants, right? I thought that's why it is more acidic and why people still buy peat moss. https://youtu.be/MvYZdxVipAo

Comment: Yes, it is acidic - but it doesn't have any nutrients, like coco peat.

Comment: Peat is used for two reasons: it acidify soil (some plant require it), and it can absorb a lot of water, so it can give roots necessary water without need to water so often (e.g. in sandy soils). And as last reason (usually not cited): peat is an "herbicide". nothing growth were there is much peat, so it work also as mulching.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi my main concern is regarding nutrition. I would like to use which is more beneficial to the plants. Like the guy in the video said that peat has more nutrients than coco and coco inhibits calcium uptake due to high amount of pottasium. And Bamboo says that both do not have any nutrition. Coco is very cheap here compared to peat moss.

Comment: I've learn the same as Bamboo (so no/low on nutrients). OTOH it is not a big concern to me: peat is being forbidden in my country (for environmental concerns, where it is taken).